# Manim LaTeX does not work due to dvi converting

Tags: python, latex, manim

I am trying to create a math animation (manim) as a side project. But when I try to use LaTeX, it gives an error.

```
ValueError: latex error converting to dvi. See log output above or the log file: ...
```

I tried looking at other solutions, but none of them helped me. Here is the code:

```
given = Tex(r"Given: \bigtriangleup ABC, m\angle B = 90", font_size=50)
```

Comment: updating the installation doesn't work

Comment: Are you in math mode? Try `Given: $\bigtriangleup$ ABC, m$\angle$ B = 90`

Comment: Thank you so much! Do I just put dollar signs around the latex parts?

Answer (score 0):

Using a `MathTex` object instead of just a `Tex` object fixes the error:

```
given = MathTex(r"Given: \bigtriangleup ABC, m\angle B = 90", font_size=50)
```